# Strange Bootstrap dropdown behavior

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange dropdown behavior on my website: https://dersuchendee.github.io/sitomanzoni/sposipromessi.html

Every time something is selected, one of the two dropdowns goes down. Then, if there is a selection of both sides, everything returns to normal. I checked for closed tags on an HTML editor and it seems there aren't any, but something must be wrong in the tags as other users' suggestions didn't work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .child-item {
            display: none

        }
        .child-item1 {
            display: none
        }

        .show {
            display: block
        }
        .show1 {
            display: block
        }

#sinistra {
  float:left;
  width:50%


}
#destra {
  float:right;
  width:50%

}




    </style>

    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- As a heading -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Variants mining - Manzoni</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="fermoelucia.html">Fermo e Lucia </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="sposipromessi.html" <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>>Sposi Promessi</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="sinistra">
    <form>
        <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
                <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Scegli i capitoli da confrontare...</label>
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option value="1">Capitolo I</option>
                    <option value="2">Capitolo II</option>
                    <option value="3">Capitolo III</option>
                    <option value="4">Capitolo IV</option>
                    <option value="5">Capitolo V</option>
                    <option value="6">Capitolo VI</option>
                    <option value="7">Capitolo VII</option>
                    <option value="8">Capitolo VIII</option>
                </select>
                <div>
                    <div id="1" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542635" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542635/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="2" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542638" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542638/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="3" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542640" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542640/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="4" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542642" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542642/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="5" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542644" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542644/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="6" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542645" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542645/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="7" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542646" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542646/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div id="8" class="child-item">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542648" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542648/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col" id="destra">
<form>
    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col">
            <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect2"></label>
            <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect2">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="11">Capitolo I</option>
                <option value="22">Capitolo II</option>
                <option value="33">Capitolo III</option>
                <option value="44">Capitolo IV</option>
                <option value="55">Capitolo V</option>
                <option value="66">Capitolo VI</option>
                <option value="77">Capitolo VII</option>
                <option value="88">Capitolo VIII</option>
            </select>
            <div>
                <div id="11" class="child-item">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542635" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542635/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="22" class="child-item">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542638" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542638/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="33" class="child-item">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542640" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542640/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="44" class="child-item">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542642" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542642/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="55" class="child-item">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542644" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542644/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="66" class="child-item">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542645" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542645/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="77" class="child-item">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542646" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542646/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div id="88" class="child-item">
                  <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2542648" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2542648/embed" data-height="550px"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>



</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    <script>
        $('#inlineFormCustomSelect').change(function() {
        $('.child-item').removeClass('show'); // hide all visible
            $('#' + $( this ).val()).addClass('show'); // Show what is necessary
        });

    </script>
    <script>
    $('#inlineFormCustomSelect2').change(function() {
    $('.child-item1').removeClass('show1'); // hide all visible
        $('#' + $( this ).val()).addClass('show1'); // Show what is necessary
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add `pull-left` to each of the `<div class="col">` elements ...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have set `align-items-center` to the `form-row`. This causes the neighbouring column to jump down since it wants to appear centred.

Removing `align-items-center` from

```html
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
 ...
</div>
```

should do the job.

But it seems that your HTML tree is not entirely Bootstrap conform. Maybe you have a quick read in the [Bootstrap Docs.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)

---

#### UPDATE

Like I've mentioned before, your markup is pretty messed up. Also your jQuery does not make a lot of sense. I have created an example for you to get an idea what I mean. **I would still suggest that you read the Bootstrap Docs as well as some basic jQuery before you continue!**

```js
$('#inlineFormCustomSelect').change(function() {
  $('.child-item').removeClass('show'); // hide all visible
  $('#' + $( this ).val()).addClass('show'); // Show what is necessary
});

$('#inlineFormCustomSelect2').change(function() {
    $('.child-item1').removeClass('show1'); // hide all visible
    $('#' + $( this ).val()).addClass('show1'); // Show what is necessary
});
```

```css
.child-item {
  display: none; 
  height: 40vh;
  background: yellow;
}
.child-item1 { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
.show1 { display: block; }
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- As a heading -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Variants mining - Manzoni</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="fermoelucia.html">Fermo e Lucia </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="sposipromessi.html"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span>Sposi Promessi</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- the form row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" id="sinistra">

        <!-- start form -->
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">

            <!--first option select -->
            <div class="col">
              <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Scegli i capitoli da confrontare...</label>
              <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="1">Capitolo I</option>
                <option value="2">Capitolo II</option>
                <option value="3">Capitolo III</option>
                <option value="4">Capitolo IV</option>
                <option value="5">Capitolo V</option>
                <option value="6">Capitolo VI</option>
                <option value="7">Capitolo VII</option>
                <option value="8">Capitolo VIII</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <!-- second option select -->
            <div class="col">
              <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect2">Another label</label>
              <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect2">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="11">Capitolo I</option>
                <option value="22">Capitolo II</option>
                <option value="33">Capitolo III</option>
                <option value="44">Capitolo IV</option>
                <option value="55">Capitolo V</option>
                <option value="66">Capitolo VI</option>
                <option value="77">Capitolo VII</option>
                <option value="88">Capitolo VIII</option>
              </select>
            </div>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- END the form row -->

    <!-- the content row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

        <div id="1" class="child-item">
          <h2>Item 1</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="2" class="child-item">
          <h2>Item2</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div> <!-- END the content row -->

  </div> <!-- end container -->

</body>
```

Comment: Done, but it doesn't work... I get the same behavior as before